# Проблема со 100% высотой экрана

Tags: html, css

Возникает проблема со 100% высотой экрана для секции `.aside {}` выставлял, но проблема не исчезает. Остаются такие вот промежутки. Как поправить? Спасибо!
https://c2n.me/43vn4SB

```
html, body, #app, .container, .aside {
height: 100%;
}
```

Ссылка на код:
https://jsfiddle.net/8te42amp/

Comment: Это нужно делать через `min-height:100%;`. И верстать нужно правильно и со смыслом, без повторений, а не как у вас. Очень грязная верстка. Хотя правится там всего в 5 местах. Всего 5 мест и у вас, все получится.

Comment: Это normalize.css, и всё собрано webpack-ом

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам не в % нужно, а в [относительных единицах](https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/).

```
html, body, #app, .container, .aside {
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В стилях

```
.aside {
  height: 100%;
```

поменять на

```
.aside {
  min-height: 100vh;
```